# How can I use special characters like @ in vue-i18n?

Tags: vue.js, yaml, internationalization, vue-i18n

I am using vue-i18n for localizing my forms. I have an email field that has a placeholder which contains an example email address that includes an `@` symbol.

```yaml
emailPlaceholder: 'eg: test@example.com'
```

Despite the quotes around the string, I got the following error

```
[plugin:unplugin-vue-i18n] Invalid linked format (error code: 10) in en.yaml

1  |  eg: test@example.com
   |          ^
```

Why is vue-i18n giving me an error despite the string being in quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that vue-i18n has a number of [special characters](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax#special-characters) that need to be escaped but YAML escaping methods like backslash will NOT work.

Instead, use [literal interpretation](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/syntax#literal-interpolation). This means using `{}` brackets to surround a string inside a string.

```yaml
emailPlaceholder: "{'eg: test@example.com'}"
```

More about this can be found in this [github issue](https://github.com/nuxt-modules/i18n/issues/2116).